# How to dynamically group a list and select values using linq query in C#?

Tags: c#, list, linq, lambda, dynamic

I have an input list **test**

```
class Tracker
{
    public string Toolid {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public int length {get;set;}
    public int breadth {get;set;}
    public int height {get;set;}

}

List<Tracker> test = new List<Tracker>();
test.Add( new Tracker {Toolid="A.1",Description ="ABC",length = 10, breadth =10,height = 50});
test.Add( new Tracker {Toolid="A.1",Description ="ABC", length = 10, breadth =10,height = 50});
test.Add( new Tracker {Toolid="C.1",Description ="ABCD", length = 10, breadth =10,height = 50});
test.Add( new Tracker {Toolid="D.1",Description ="Admin123", length = 10, breadth =10,height = 50});
```

This list contain more values like weight, colour etc.
For better understanding I have added only 5 member variables in the class **Tracker**.

I need to Group the list **test** based on the values of another list (**grpList**).
This list (**grpList** ) is dynamic, hence the number of parameter and values in the list may change. 
**So I need a dynamic Group By of list using LINQ query.**

case 1 : sometimes this list **grpList**  contain 2 values .

```
List <string> grpList = new List<string>();

grpList.Add(ToolId);
grpList.Add(Description);
```

if So , I have to group the list **test** with ToolId and Description,

case 2 : if list **grpList**  contain N values , I have to group the list **test** with 'N' values .

The number of values in the **grpList** varies. I have group the main list **test** using the values in grpList. If **grpList** contain 2 values ,group the **test** list with 2 values . if  If **grpList** contain 5 values , group the **test** list with 5 values.

NB : I need to Group the list **test** ( Main list). 
     **grpList** values only for grouping .

Comment: Could you please show the expected result of your query?

Comment: Does it answer your question? [LINQ GroupBy with a dynamic group of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286297/linq-groupby-with-a-dynamic-group-of-columns)

Answer (score 0):

try reflection:

```
List<string> grpList = new List<string>();
grpList.Add("Toolid");
grpList.Add("Description");

var groups = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable>();
var all_properties = typeof(Tracker).GetProperties();

foreach ( var prop_name in grpList )
{
    var prop = all_properties.First( x => x.Name == prop_name);
    var group = test.GroupBy( x =>  prop.GetValue( x ) );
    groups.Add( prop_name, group );
}
```

if you want to have an sql-like nested grouping, apply the `GroupBy` to the resulting groups:

```
var groups = new List<List<Tracker>>() { test };
foreach ( var prop_name in grpList )
{
    var prop = all_properties.First( x => x.Name == prop_name);
    var newgroups = new List<List<Tracker>>();
    foreach ( var group in groups)
    {
        var subgroups = group.GroupBy( x => prop.GetValue( x ) );                   
        newgroups.AddRange( subgroups.Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList() );                                       
    }
    groups = newgroups;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Enumerable.GroupBy Method selector predicate.
Here's how I generated the predicate and the solution seems to work.

```
public class Tracker
    {
        public string Toolid { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int length { get; set; }
        public int breadth { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Tracker> test = new List<Tracker>();
            test.Add(new Tracker { Toolid = "A.1", Description = "ABC", length = 50, breadth = 10, height = 50 });
            test.Add(new Tracker { Toolid = "A.1", Description = "ABC", length = 20, breadth = 10, height = 50 });
            test.Add(new Tracker { Toolid = "C.1", Description = "LMN", length = 10, breadth = 10, height = 50 });
            test.Add(new Tracker { Toolid = "D.1", Description = "Admin123", length = 7, breadth = 10, height = 50 });

            List<string> grpList = new List<string>();
            grpList.Add("length");
            grpList.Add("Description");

            var sourceParm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Tracker), "x");
            List<Expression> propertyExpressions = new List<Expression>();
            foreach (var f in grpList.ToArray())
            {
                Expression conv = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(sourceParm, f), typeof(object));
                propertyExpressions.Add(conv);
            }

            var concatMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod(
                                                   "Concat",
                                                    new[] { typeof(object), typeof(object), typeof(object) });
            Expression body = propertyExpressions.Aggregate((x, y) => Expression.Call(concatMethod, 
                                                                            x,
                                                                            Expression.Constant(","), 
                                                                            y));
            var groupSelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<Tracker, string>>(body, sourceParm);
            var j = test.GroupBy(groupSelector.Compile());
}
```