# C# Groupby based on different properties

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, grouping

How can we build the groupBy expressions based on multiple properties which can change in number?
I got a list of objects of class C. All the groupby examples I can find are based on pre-determined properties. How can we build groupBy expression on the fly based on number of properties passed in by the user?

Please note that I don't know exact properties as it is different for every real project. So the code cannot assume that GroupByAttribute1, GroupByAttribute2 etc will exist. Need a solution which takes all grouping input parameters and build groupby as per values of them.

```
class C
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string GroupByAttribute1 { get; set; }
     public string GroupByAttribute2 { get; set; }
     public string GroupByAttribute3 { get; set; }
}

        private static void TestGroupBy()
        {
            //grouping attribute change on the fly
            GroupBy(new List<string> { "GroupByAttribute1", "GroupByAttribute3" });
            GroupBy(new List<string> { "GroupByAttribute2" });
        }

        private static void GroupBy(List<string> groupByAttributes)
        {
            List<C> items = new List<C>
            {
                new C { Id = 0, GroupByAttribute1 = "A", GroupByAttribute2 = "C", GroupByAttribute3 = "B" },
                new C { Id = 1, GroupByAttribute1 = "A", GroupByAttribute2 = "D", GroupByAttribute3 = "B" },
                new C { Id = 2, GroupByAttribute1 = "X", GroupByAttribute2 = "N", GroupByAttribute3 = "Z" },
                new C { Id = 3, GroupByAttribute1 = "X", GroupByAttribute2 = "N", GroupByAttribute3 = "Z" }
            };

            /* Grouping based on fixed properties can be done like below
var f = items.GroupBy(i => new
            {
                Attribute1 = i.GroupByAttribute1,
                Attribute2 = i.GroupByAttribute3
            });*/

            //How to build groupBy expression based on grouping attributes that can change with the call?
var f2 = items.GroupBy(i => new
            {
                foreach (var propertyToGroupBy in groupByAttributes)
                {
                     
                 }
            });

        }
```

Comment: You need to build the expression tree and pass it to `GroupBy()`.

Comment: You need to construct a single string from the values of the chosen attributes, and then group by that.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Any examples? Thanks.

Comment: I reckon [this answer specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33287006/3744182) by [Jeff Mercado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390278/jeff-mercado) to [LINQ GroupBy with a dynamic group of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33286297/3744182) ought to work for you.  It suggests to use of the Dynamic Linq add in. But if that doesn't work for you, do the answers from [Dynamically generate LINQ queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9505189/3744182) answer your question also?  If not, can you be more specific about your difficulty?